# Extract elements from a vector within lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of length 30000 and each list element contains one vector of length 6.

Example (with a length of just 2):

```
trainLists <- list(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),c(7,8,9,10,11,12))
```

I want to  "flatten" these lists into a dataframe and create 6 factors (one corresponding to each of the elements in the vectors in the list).

Thus, the result would be:

[image]

I can accomplish this with a loop such as

```
for (i in 1:length(trainLists){
   factor1 [i] <- trainLists[[i]][1]
   factor2 [i] <- trainLists[[i]][2]
   factor3 [i] <- trainLists[[i]][3]
   factor4 [i] <- trainLists[[i]][4]
   factor5 [i] <- trainLists[[i]][5]
   factor6 [i] <- trainLists[[i]][6]
}
```

but it is horribly slow. How best to accomplish this?

Comment: See `?rbind` and `?cbind`. hint: start with testing `do.call(rbind, trainLists)` on your small data to see what it does.

Comment: To coerce to factors, you can use either `sapply/lapply`, but that will likely require another call to `as.data.frame`. Another option would something like `colwise(as.factor)(yourData)` from the **plyr** package.

Comment: Also using plyr, you could try `ldply(trainLists)` to turn your list into a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, most of what you want to do is achieved with a simple `do.call(rbind, ...)`, like this:

```
> trainLists <- list(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),c(7,8,9,10,11,12))
> trainLists
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

[[2]]
[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12

> do.call(rbind, trainLists)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    7    8    9   10   11   12
```

---

Taking things a few steps forward, you can do something like this:

```
cbind(example = seq_along(trainLists), 
      setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, trainLists)),
               paste0("Factor_", sequence(
                 max(sapply(trainLists, length))))))
#   example Factor_1 Factor_2 Factor_3 Factor_4 Factor_5 Factor_6
# 1       1        1        2        3        4        5        6
# 2       2        7        8        9       10       11       12
```